# How to find all the interfaces that extend a base interface on a given object?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a crude/basic event Subscribe/Publish system just to experiment.

I created a base `IEventListener` interface, then a generic `IEventListener<T> : IEventListener` interface on top of that, which has a function `OnEvent(T eventParam)`

I then created a test class that implemented `IEventListener<string>` and `IEventListener<int>`

I thought that by passing it through the following:

```
Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _listenersByType = new Dictionary<Type, List<object>>();

foreach(Type interfaceType in listener.GetType().GetInterfaces())
{
    if(interfaceType is IEventListener)
    {
        AddSubscriber(interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), listener);
    }
}
```

I could create a look up of Event Types to Objects to cast and publish the events to. However, when stepping through. I see it loop all the interfaces, I can see the type name is "IEventListener" but the condition is never true, and never adds my listener to the dictionary.

[Pastebin of full code](http://pastebin.com/UKx6tBas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through means of which I am unsure (I poked around in the debugger), this fixes it:

```
foreach(Type interfaceType in listener.GetType().GetInterfaces())
{
    if(interfaceType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEventListener)))
    {
        AddSubscriber(interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0], listener);
    }
}
```

But I cannot tell you why I have to check the interfaces, of the interface. Or why I have to call `interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0]` instead of `interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`.

Part of me feels like this code is bad and I've got a design issue here. I would never expect the solution to be so... Ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You could just ask the object itself if it implemets interface. For exampl i have created fake class:

```
public class SListener<T> :  IEventListener<T>
{
public void OnEvent(T eventParam)
    {
    }
}
```

and object of it

```
var s = new SListener<string>();
```

if i ask

```
bool t = (s is IEventListener);
```

it is true.

So your  subscribe mthod could be like :

```
public void Subscribe(object listener)
{
   if(listener is IEventListener)
   {
       AddSubscriber(interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), listener);
   }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help me separate out all the `IEventListener<T>`s that the object implements though

Comment: Sure it help, you just have to change your Subscribe metgod :    public void Subscribe(object listener)
    {
       if(listener is IEventListener)
       {
          AddSubscriber(interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), listener);
       }
    }

Comment: I need ALL the `IEventListener<T>` interfaces, there could be multiple, I.e. `public class TestClass : IEventListener<int>, IEventListener<string>` - when I subscribe that one object, it needs to end up in two lists. One for `string` one for `int`.

Comment: And ALL the IEventListener<T> are inherited from the simple IEventListener, aren't they? So you could alwayscall if (listener is IEventListener).

Comment: That's what I was doing in my original question and it wasn't working... The issue is I want to break out all the generic types and store the listener against each type. Not simply store the listener if it is a listener.